# Reload image on loop (JavaScript / HTML)

Tags: javascript, html

I have a Python script that changes an image every few seconds and I need to display that image on a website without the user having to reload the page every few seconds.
I tried this code:

```
function refreshImage(imgElement, imgURL){    
  // create a new timestamp 
  var timestamp = new Date().getTime();  

  var el = document.getElementById(imgElement);  

  var queryString = "?t=" + timestamp;    

  el.src = imgURL + queryString;    
}    

while (true){
  refreshImage(cameraFeed, "image.jpg")
}
```

In a loop but I couldn't get it to work.

If anyone could help me out it would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Instead of an infinite loop using `while (true)` you can try using setInverval() like this `setInterval(refreshImage(){ refreshImage(cameraFeed, "image.jpg"); }, 3000);` It will call the refreshImage function every 3 seconds.

Comment: Another way, if you don't want to use `setInterval` to refresh image in some exact time, is to use [web socket](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/WebSocket) which is providing full-duplex communication channels. You can use _socket.io_ which is implementable in both, [Python](https://python-socketio.readthedocs.io/en/latest/) and [JavaScript](https://socket.io/). It will reload image only when your Python script tells to do it.

Comment: Didn't work. I think something might be wrong with the function.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As *Ozgur Sar* suggested in comments, you can use `setInterval()`. For example like this:

```js
const refreshImage = (imgElement, imgURL) => () => 
  imgElement.src = imgURL + "?" + new Date().getTime();

const cameraFeed = document.querySelector(".cameraFeed");
setInterval(refreshImage(cameraFeed, "https://loremflickr.com/320/240"), 3000);
```

```html
<img class="cameraFeed" src="https://loremflickr.com/320/240"/>
```

---

Another way, if you don't want to use setInterval to refresh image in some exact time, is to use [web socket](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/WebSocket) which is providing full-duplex communication channels. You can use socket.io which is implementable in both, [Python](https://python-socketio.readthedocs.io/en/latest/) and [JavaScript](https://socket.io/). It will reload image only when your Python script tells to do it.

Comment: Image still doesn't update. I'm referencing a local file, would that have something to do with it?

Comment: Has been local file really changed? It's hard to determine problem without full example but in the snippet I've provided the URL stays same and only parameters are changing (as you have provided in your question). For me it works on my local pretty well.

Answer (score 0):

I have found out how to refresh it by refreshing the page instead of trying to reload the image.

```
<META HTTP-EQUIV="REFRESH" CONTENT="1"></META>
```

Comment: This will reload whole page and all of it's content. Gladly it might be ok for you but it is not very efficient.

Comment: Luckily, this page purely serves the purpose of displaying this single image. I am aware it is quite an innefiicent method but it serves the purpose for now.

Answer (score -4):

Instead of using

> `var queryString = "?t=" + timestamp;`

You try it `Math.random()`

> `var queryString = "?" + Math.random();`

Comment: timestamp definitely ensures a new value every time to avoid it being loaded from cache. -1